# Could not GET json : Infinite recursion

Tags: java, json, spring

I am getting and infinite loop while trying to perform GET to a publisher repository.

Publisher:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "publisher")
public class Publisher {

    @Id
    private Long publisherID;

    private String name;
    private String location;

    public Publisher(@JsonProperty("publisherID") Long publisherID,
                     @JsonProperty("name") String name,
                     @JsonProperty("location") String location) {
        this.publisherID = publisherID;
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
    }

    @JsonManagedReference(value="Book-Publisher")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "publisher", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Book> books;

    public Publisher() {
    }
}
```

Book:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {

    @Id
```

private Long id;

```
private String name;

@JsonBackReference(value="Book-Publisher")
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="publisherID")
private Publisher publisher;

private int publicationYear;
private int amount;

@JsonManagedReference(value="BookAuthors-Book")
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<BookAuthors> bookAuthors;

@JsonManagedReference(value="BookGenres-Book")
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<BookGenres> bookGenres;

public Book(@JsonProperty("id") Long id,
            @JsonProperty("name") String name,
            @JsonProperty("publisherID") Long publisherID,
            @JsonProperty("publicationYear") int publicationYear,
            @JsonProperty("amount") int amount) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.publicationYear = publicationYear;
    this.amount = amount;
    PublisherService publisherService = BeanUntil.getBean(PublisherService.class);
    this.publisher = publisherService.findByID(publisherID).get();

}
@JsonManagedReference(value="RentedBook-Book")
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<RentedBook> rentedBooks;

public Book() {
}
```

}

> 2020-04-10 16:43:02.483  WARN 672 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.vanyasav.domain.Publisher["books"])]

Full code is available here:

https://github.com/vanyasav/Library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When list of `Publisher` serialized for response, all getter method of `Publisher` field are called. So, `Publisher` relational field `books`'s getter are also called to setvalue. This happened recursivly.That's cause of infinite recursion.

Its better to not use Entity as response. Create a DTO class for publisher then map publisher entity value into DTO then send response.

For dynamically map one model to another you can use `ModleMapper`

Comment: Yes, thank you, ModelMapper solution works just fine.